# How can I animate the Margin of a Stackpanel with a storyboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to use it, but it doesnt't work, I wanna create a tile animation, in code behind, or if you know a project for this gol, pls write me

```
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        while(true){
                        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.15));

                        // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
                        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();

                        myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
                        myDoubleAnimation1.From = -173
                        myDoubleAnimation1.To = 173;
                        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
                        sb.Duration = duration;

                        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);

                        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, image);

                        // Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
                        // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
                        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath(StackPanel.MarginProperty));

                        // Begin the animation.
                        sb.Begin();}
                    });
```

Comment: Margin's type is Thickness - not double (which is what double animation is used for). You need to animate the content of the Margin property, which, being a struct, I don't know if you can do. What are you trying to do.

Comment: Are you really creating Storyboard after Storyboard in an endless loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating Margin Bottom Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507954/animating-margin-bottom-silverlight)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`ThicknessAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.thicknessanimation.aspx) instead of a [`DoubleAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx). It's almost the same.

**Edit:**

If you want to make the Animation endless use [`Timeline.RepeatBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.repeatbehavior.aspx).

```
myThicknessAnimation1.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
```

Comment: thank your LPL the answer, can You write me it in XAML? please

Comment: Please see the Examples section in the ThicknessAnimation link I gave you.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the working example, if anybody needs:

```
//Animate margin for Label, named "label" from right to left. from 300 to 0.

var sb = new Storyboard();
var ta = new ThicknessAnimation();
ta.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0);
ta.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, "label");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ta, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));

ta.From = new Thickness(300, 30, 0, 0);
ta.To = new Thickness(0, 30, 0, 0);
ta.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

sb.Children.Add(ta);
sb.Begin(this);
```